# Docker container exits despite having a running service

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-services, dockerfile

I am new to `Docker`. I'd like my `Windwows-ServerCore` based container to perform a task at regular time bound intervals. For this reason, I decided to install a service in my container, which can trigger these tasks at regular intervals.

This is my dockerfile -

```
FROM test2
SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]
RUN New-LocalUser -Name "testuser" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "CrackPassword!" -Force) -FullName "Test.User" -Description "LocalAdministrator"
RUN Add-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators -Member  testuser -Verbose
RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/InstallUtil.exe" /username=.\testuser /password=CrackPassword! /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack TestDockerService.exe
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell"] 
CMD Start-Service \""DockerService\""
```

The issue is that this container exits after starting, presumably `Powershell`, as the entry command, starts the service, and with its work over, ends, taking the container down with it.

How can I enable the container, and by extension, my service to keep running?

I read about the `-d` argument with `docker run`, which will `detach` the container so docker won't monitor it anymore, but it'll also mean losing access to `STDIN` etc. which I may need. Is there another way to accomplish the same, or is `-d` the correct approach?

Perhaps another option could be to start the service from a `batch file` and run an infinite loop after the start command, which allows the container to remain alive?

On a wider note, how does one keep a `Docker container` running, even if a service isn't running, for inspection and debugging with an interactive session, say?

Comment: For something like this it might be better to use the task scheduler to run the container at the time intervals, if that's a possibility.

Comment: Task scheduler on host OS to start the container on schedule? It's possible, however, the container / service also needs to listen to certain notifications from inside and react to them, so task scheduler from host OS to start - stop the container isn't feasible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker is designed to stay alive until its main process (with `PID 1`) exits. When it happens, container is treated as stopped. This main process is normally not supposed to be a background one.

Your container runs `Start-Service` command, it successfully registers and starts the background service **and exits**. And, because it is your main process, container stops.

You have different ways to keep container alive, but all of them end up with having main process alive. Not sure with Windows container, but simply having a sleep loop works.
The first thing coming to my mind is simply having `ping 127.0.0.1 -t > NUL` command at the end of the script.

Comment: `ping 127.0.0.1 -t > NUL` will consume networking resources, might be better to have a while loop with a sleep

Comment: So, use `CMD` within `DockerFile` to specify a batch file with a  `NET` or `SC` command to start the service and have a WHILE loop at the end? Then run this with a simple `docker run -it` for interactive session?

Comment: @arco444 agree, have given `ping` to show an idea of keeping process alive, but not going to protect it as a best-in-class approach

Comment: @user1173240, yes, you can wrap your script into a command file and call it from `ENTRYPOINT/CMD`. This is preferable. Another solution - put all commands in `Dockerfile` like `CMD ["sh", "-c", "job1 && job2 && ..."]` but I dont know the syntax for Windows shell (this will work in Linux)

Comment: @ user1173240... Could you answer the question with a full example of the script? it would be beneficial for us trying to learn...

Answer (score 0):

I was running apache in a windows-based container, which by default also runs as a service. The solution with `CMD ping 127.0.0.1 -t` works to keep the container alive, but is not really nice and consumes extra resources. Using something like `more` or `pause` that normally would wait for user input didn't help - the container exited anyway. I finally ended up with disabling and stopping the apache service and added a `CMD httpd.exe -n apache` at the end of my dockerfile to start the apache process in interactive (foreground) mode.

Answer (score 0):

The `powershell` need's to be added to the end of `CMD`.

```
FROM ...
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]
RUN ...
CMD Start-Service DockerService; powershell
```

Also, you can overwrite all your `CMD` commands by simply adding `powershell` to the end of your RUN command:

```
docker run -it ... powershell
```

This approach can be useful in case when you have a bunch of bootstrap scripts witch you would like to dismiss when run container.